# Conexão Java MySql e FTP

Tags: java, conexão

Minha duvida não é sobre como fazer uma conexão com ftp ou mysql, pois isso na estou conseguindo.

Faço a conexão usando os parametros como host, porta, usuario e senha. Meu codigo fonte armazena essas informações. Pensando na questão de segurança, como é implementada uma conexão sem que essas informações fiquem no codigo fonte? Pensei em criar uma tabela num banco com o usuario e senha e meu app consultar essa tabela, porem na conexão eu uso como parametro o usuario e senha desse banco.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é a melhor forma, mas uma que eu já usei e funcionou:
- para cada usuário do sistema, criar um usuário no banco de dados, então o usuário fará o login no sistema com um login do banco de dados, desta forma, não ficaria nenhuma informação sobre usuário e senha armazenados nos códigos do sistema.

Bônus: Além de dados de conexão não ficarem nos códigos do sistema, você também poderá definir permissões no banco de dados por usuário, gerando assim, uma segurança a mais (não excluindo as permissões gerenciadas pelo sistema).

Espero ter ajudado!